# Molting in arthropods

Tags: entomology, biodiversity

Do all the arthropods molt ? Which ones do not molt ? Why don't they need to molt ?

I tried googling this - but did not get satisfactory answers.

Answer (score 1):

in my opinion all arthropods molt. In fact arthropods are a part of clade called ecdysozoa, the members of which undergo ecdysis (molting).

Molting is necessary because arthropods have an exoskeleton which has to be removed if the organism has to grow.